# Php.ini settings pose security risk?

Tags: php, security

I checked my php.ini file using //phpinfo(); and noticed somethings among them are:-

```
include_path :..
open_basedir novalue
```

do these pose security risks?

what should they be?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php - the settings are described there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The . is the current directory. The : is a delimiter.

open_basedir novalue just means its off.